# Use spark-streaming as a scheduler

Tags: scala, apache-spark, spark-streaming

I have a Spark job that reads from an Oracle table into a dataframe.  The way it seems the jdbc.read method works is to pull an entire table in at once, so I constructed a spark-submit job to work in batch.  Whenever I have data I need manipulated I put it in a table and run the spark-submit.

However, I would like this to be more event driven...essentially I want it so anytime data is moved into this table it is run through Spark, so I can have events in a UI drive these insertions and spark is just running.  I was thinking about using a spark streaming context just to have it watching and operating on the table all the time, but with a long wait between streaming contexts.  This way I can use the results (also written to Oracle in part) to trigger a deletion of the read table and not run data more than once.

Is this a bad idea?  Will this work?  It seems more elegant than using a cron-job.

Comment: What do you mean by long wait between streaming contexts? Spark Streaming operates in micro batches. You can set very low batch intervals as well as high ones. It depends on your use case. How frequent the data in the database is updated. In one of my projects we read data every 1 second from the source and pass it to spark streaming.

Comment: It would be irregular, but I wouldn't want to keep reading the same data.  I actually think that using Kafka as a message queue for table reads would be better, but we're trying to orchestrate this more quickly.